# uwsgi -- unavailable modifier requested: 80 --

Tags: python, uwsgi

centos 7, uwsgi 2.0.17.1
I start uwsgi with the following command:

```
nohup uwsgi server.ini &
```

server.ini:

[image: server.init]

On each request writes to log the following line:

```
-- unavailable modifier requested: 80 --
```

Comment: A couple of things: How have you installed uWSGI? Does the request still go through? As far as I can see, `80` is no modifier in the default configuration.

Comment: Please don't take a screenshot where text would be more helpful.

Comment: pip install uwsgi